# How to configure Emacs for Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote, editors

I'm new to Emacs. I followed some intructions to use it for Asymptote but that does not work.

In *~.emacs*, I have:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp")
(load "asy-mode.el")
```

And in the folder *~/.emacs.d/site-lisp*, I have the file *asy-mode.el* containing

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:\PortableApps\MikTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64")
(autoload 'asy-mode "asy-mode.el" "Asymptote major mode." t)
(autoload 'lasy-mode "asy-mode.el" "hybrid Asymptote/Latex major mode." t)
(autoload 'asy-insinuate-latex "asy-mode.el" "Asymptote insinuate LaTeX." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.asy$" . asy-mode))
```

Now when I open an ASY file in Emacs, I see nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on my new miktex installation on W10,
I typed in my init file (~/.emacs.d/init.el)

```
 (add-to-list 'load-path ( format "%s\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX\\asymptote" (getenv "USERPROFILE")))
   (requires 'asy-mode)
```

After Emacs  restart a file with .asy extension is opened in asy-mode

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't work for me. But if I put the files **asy-init.el**, **asy-mode.el** and **asy-keyboard.el** in **~/.emacs.d** and I run `emacs -l C:\Users\sdl96354\.emacs.d\asy-mode.el` then it works.

Comment: I've found. I put  the contents of the file **asy-mode.el** in the file **~/.emacs** and it works.

Comment: There are plenty of solutions. The `asy-mode.el` file must be in the `load-path`. Loading the file is not a very good idea unless you exclusively use Emacs to edit asymptote files. You should prefer `require` over `load`.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Would you know whether there is an advantage in using Emacs as compared to VS code with the Asymptote extension?